# why does operator < have a compiler error for Java generics?

Tags: java, generics

Why does the condition `key < x[mid]` below cause the compiler to complain that the operator is undefined?

In C++ this would be a compile time warning only if the type T didn't support operator `<` semantics. How do you do the equivalent in Java?

```
package search;

    public class BinarySearch<T>
    {
        public boolean binary_search_iterative (T[] x, T key)
        {
            int size = x.length;
            if ( size == 0 ) { return false; }

            int end = size - 1;

            int start = 0;

            while ( start <= end)
            {
                int mid = (end + start)/2 ;
                if (key < x[mid])
                {
                    end = mid - 1;
                }
                else if ( key > key[mid])
                {
                    start = mid + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Answer is simple, these are two different languages following two different syntax.

Comment: @JunedAhsan and "How do you do the equivalent in Java?"?

Comment: I think that is because key is a template variable here. I could be replaced by any object not necessarily a number. for such objects you cannot have comparison using '<' operator.

Comment: Thanks Blorgbeard for clarifying.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no operator overloading in Java. To obtain a similar result you should look into [`Comparable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) which is meant to provide the same functionality to objects.

So in your case it would be:

```
key.compareTo(x[mid]) < 0
```

But to make this work you must provide a bounded type variable, `T` is not enough because the compiler can't infer that types what  used in place of `T` implement `Comparable` so you should use:

```
public class BinarySearch<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

This because generics are not implemented like in C++ in which templates are built during compilation phase according to the types that use them. You must explicitly state what your `T` is because the type checker requires so.

Comment: +1 and `T extends Comparable<? super T>` for slightly more flexibility.

Comment: makes sense thanks for this detail. Also, I will have to read up on @PaulBellora answer as well

Comment: Paul by changing it to  T extends Comparable <? super T> doesn't it exclude Comparable<T> since the super class will only compare items that are super classes of T?

Comment: @bjackfly: No, the super-type relation is reflexive so T is a valid super-type of T.

Comment: @Jack: Ok so I am bit confused, could you please explain this for me? In reading the Oracle java book it has the following method example, but maybe this is not reflexive? It is using Java.awt.Container hiearchy as an example:  void describeComponent (CustomComponent<? super Cotainer> ref ) and then says the following:
Note that Container itself is omitted, along with all its subclasses.

Answer (score 9):

In Java you cannot overload operators.

The way this would normally be solved is to have your key class implement the `Comparable<T>` interface, and override its `compareTo()` method.

You would then limit your type parameter `T` to only types that implement Comparable, e.g.:

```
BinarySearch<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

And use `compareTo()` instead of `<`.

Answer (score 1):

> In C++ this would be a compile time warning only if the type T didn't support operator < semantics.

Correct. In Java there are *no* types `T` that can be used in a generic declaration that *do* support operator <. So you get a compilation error.

Comment: There are: `static <T extends Integer> boolean compare(List<T> list) { return list.get(0) < list.get(1); }` The point is that there are *some* types T which *do not* support the operator `<`.

Answer (score 0):

T is autoboxed always to an Object. **`<` is allowed for primitive numbers in java only.**

Try this for any *primitive numbers* or classes that *extends from Number*:

```
package search;

public strictfp class BinarySearch<T extends Number>
{
    public boolean binary_search_iterative (T[] x, T key)
    {
        int size = x.length;
        if ( size == 0 ) { return false; }

        int end = size - 1;

        int start = 0;

        while ( start <= end)
        {
            int mid = (end + start)/2 ;
            if (key.doubleValue() < x[mid].doubleValue())
            {
                end = mid - 1;
            }
            else if ( key.doubleValue() > x[mid].doubleValue())
            {
                start = mid + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinarySearch<Integer> bs = new BinarySearch<Integer>();
        bs.binary_search_iterative(new Integer[]{1,2}, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to convert all Numbers to doubles. Using compareTo() will not only cover all non-Number cases, but will also use a comparison method optimized for the actual type.

Comment: No autoboxing here.  `T` **is** a reference type.  Only reference types can be used as type parameters.

Comment: @JasonC This works for Numbers only (as i wrote). Therefore you need to convert it to Double.

Comment: @PeterRader I see your point, I had forgotten that Number is not Comparable.

Comment: Oh, ok, now i understand what youv tried to say. `Number` cant be comperable(!) because of the `Double.NaN`-Value.... too bad. Btw BigDecimal extends from `Number` **and** from `Comparable` coz doubleValue() not preciesly enouth.